# Failed to add gRPC as dependency to other Bazel project on macOS

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, bazel

I am building my C++ project using Bazel on macOS, and I added the gRPC as one of the deps

FYI, I successfully built with same settings on Linux, however, it fails for me on macOS.

WORKSPACE

```
git_repository(
  name = "com_github_grpc_grpc",
  remote = "https://github.com/grpc/grpc",
  tag = "v1.20.1"
)

load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:grpc_deps.bzl", "grpc_deps")
grpc_deps()
```

and the build file for my module

a.BUILD

```
cc_library(
  name = "s12",
  srcs = glob(
    ["**/*.cc"],
  ),
  hdrs = glob(
    ["**/*.h",],
  ),
  deps = [
    "@com_github_grpc_grpc//:grpc++",
    "@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf",
  ],
)
```

and in linking stage I got following error:

```
[libprotobuf ERROR external/com_github_sc_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:58] File already exists in database: google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
[libprotobuf FATAL external/com_github_sc_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1370] CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException: CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
external/bazel_tools/tools/test/test-setup.sh: line 310: 63268 Abort trap: 6           "${TEST_PATH}" "$@" 2>&1
```

Apparently, some file is included multiple times, however, I couldn't figure out why.